# Determine, if a user has been authenticated using id_token_hint

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I implemented getting claims via id_token_hint in one of my user journeys. Now want to check, if a user has been authenticated using a valid token later on.

My idea is to use a claims transformation that sets a claim `isTokenAuthentication` to `true` if the sub claim is successfully extracted in `IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims` technical profile.

However, when invoking the policy with id_token_hint, the `sub` claim gets added to the claims bag, but `isTokenAuthentication` is missing.

Here is what my current steps look like:

**Relying Party**

```
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="MyUserJourney" />
    <!--Step 2: Add the following node immediately after the DefaultUserJourney element-->
    <UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="{Settings:AppInsightsInstrumentationKey}" DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
      <!-- <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution> -->
    </UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
```

**Extract Claims Profile**

```
  <TechnicalProfile Id="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims">
    <DisplayName> My ID Token Hint TechnicalProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="None" />
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="METADATA">{Settings:id_token_hint_MetadataEndPoint}</Item>
      <Item Key="issuer">{Settings:id_token_hint_Issuer}</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <OutputClaims>
      <!--Read the subject cliam from the id_token_hint-->
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub"/>
    </OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CheckIfSubPresent" />
    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  </TechnicalProfile>
```

**ClaimsTransformation**

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CheckIfSubPresent" TransformationMethod="DoesClaimExist">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isTokenAuthentication" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Any Ideas what the Problem is?
Are there any other good ways to determine, if a user got into the flow with a valid id_token_hint?

Comment: Hmm, could it be that you need to specify a value for the isTokenAuthentication claim?

Comment: @juunas I already tried to pass it into the relying party (inputclaim with default value = false) so the claim is present from the beginning, but it looks like it doesn`t get changed by the claims transformation

Comment: Have you tried Application Insights logging for the user journey? With that + the B2C extension for VS Code, you could see what happened in the transformation.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see the getclaims/IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims step getting logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that the **IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims** supports output claims transformations.

You can create [a claims transformation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile):

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="ClaimsTransformation-CheckIfSubPresent">
  <DisplayName>Unlink Facebook</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isTokenAuthentication" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CheckIfSubPresent" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Then add this claims transformation technical profile after the **IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims** one to the user journey:

```xml
<OrchestrationSteps>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="GetClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="IdTokenHint-ExtractClaims" />
  <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckIfSubPresent" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ClaimsTransformation-CheckIfSubPresent" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  ...
</OrchestrationSteps>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Also had the Idea this morning and just tested something similar. Works perfectly :)